# How to serialize as string the key in kafka messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using confluent-kafka and I need to serialize my keys as strings and produce some messages. I have a working code for the case where I retrieve the schema from the schema registry and use it to produce a message. The problem is that it fails when I am trying to read the schema from a local file instead.

The code below is the working one for the schema registry:

```
import argparse
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroSerializer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringSerializer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
import avro.schema

SCHEMA_HOST = '192.168.40.10'
TOPIC = 'my_topic'
SCHEMA = 'path/to/schema.avsc'

# Just parse argumments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Avro Kafka Generator")
parser.add_argument('--schema_registry_host', default=SCHEMA_HOST, help="schema registry host")
parser.add_argument('--schema', type=str, default=SCHEMA, help="schema to produce under")
parser.add_argument('--topic', type=str, default=TOPIC, help="topic to publish to")
parser.add_argument('--frequency', type=float, default=1.0, help="number of message per second")

args = parser.parse_args()

# Actual code
schema_registry_conf = {'url': "http://{}:8081".format(SCHEMA_HOST)}
schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)
schema = schema_registry_client.get_latest_version(subject_name=TOPIC + "-value")
# schema = schema_registry_client.get_schema(schema.schema_id)
schema = schema_registry_client.get_schema(schema.schema_id)
schema_str = schema.schema_str
pro_conf = {"auto.register.schemas": False}
avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_registry_client=schema_registry_client, schema_str=schema_str, conf=pro_conf)
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "{}:9095".format(args.schema_registry_host),
        'schema.registry.url': "http://{}:8081".format(args.schema_registry_host)}
# avro_producer = AvroProducer(conf, default_value_schema=value_schema)
producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "{}:9095".format(SCHEMA_HOST),
                 'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8'),
                 'value.serializer': avro_serializer}
avro_producer = SerializingProducer(producer_conf)
```

But when I try to use a variation for the local file it fails:

```
# Read schema from local file
value_schema = avro.schema.Parse(open(args.schema, "r").read())
schema_str = open(args.schema, "r").read().replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')

pro_conf = {"auto.register.schemas": True}
avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_registry_client=schema_registry_client, schema_str=schema_str, conf=pro_conf)
```

this part is common to both versions:

```
producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "{}:9095".format(SCHEMA_HOST),
                 'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8'),
                 'value.serializer': avro_serializer}
avro_producer = SerializingProducer(producer_conf)
avro_producer.produce(topic=args.topic, value=message)
```

The error I am getting is the following;

> KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="'RecordSchema'
> object has no attribute 'lookup_schema'"}

Obviously, it's not the best approach and I guess if it worked the code seems ugly and error prone. But it doesn't even work so, I need some help on how I could read a local schema and use the `AvroSerializer` afterwards.

Comment: Your error is about the value, yet your question title is about the keys (which you aren't even sending)... Which is it?

Comment: Until the key String serialization I wasn't sending any key but now I need to impose this limitation about the key. I am not sure how can I send the key (or if I have to be to be honest)

Comment: No, it's not required, but `producer.send(topic, key="some string"...)`. However, that's not going to fix the error you're getting. Besides that, I don't see much of a difference between using the registry and a file. Maybe replacing the whitespace though isn't the best idea

Comment: And how am I supposed to get past the error message then?